# Href links are loaded

Tags: php, html, sql

On my website, I quoted Wikipédia and I added a link to the article on Wikipédia but I just realized that when I load my page, it was very long because my page loaded the wikipedia page too !

This is how the link is :

```
<a href="<?php echo $data['link']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $data['source']; ?></a>
```

So *link* and *source* are columns in my *author* table.

```
$data['link'] = http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphaël_(peintre)
$data['source'] = Wikipédia
```

When the code is like the one above, it loads the wikipedia page after my page is loaded and when I replace the href with #, it's ok...

Is that normal ?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: What are the values of $data['link'] and $data['source']

Comment: Please clarify - do you mean that the Wikipedia content appears inside your webpage? or your browser is loading the Wikipedia page via new tab? or you notice a http request in network tools?

Comment: @Daan I edited with the values of the data.. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Steve Well, if I look at the bottom of my browser, I can see that the browser is loading the wikipédia content but the content in itself doesn't appear and no tab is opened...

Comment: Open developer tools and look at the network tab - that will show you what is being requested from where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just realized that this the extension WikiWand for Google Chrome... Well, that is just weird to load a wiki page every time there is a link...

Thank you for your answers...